# Android JSON parsing Error 1999

Tags: android, json, eclipse, genymotion

Been working on parsing a JSON object for two days. I got everything working for plain java but had problems bringing it over to android.

I then elected to use the code provided [here](http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-asynctask-json-parsing-example.html). Ironically the json I'm trying to parse also has an id/email/name (and others)(the example's json only has those three). Instead of "user" as the example shows though, the json object is "orders".

I'm using Genymotion and have posted the logcat error. I'd be happy to post the code if that'd help.

I really appreciate any assistance!

```
07-15 06:19:57.746: I/Choreographer(1999): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-15 06:19:59.258: I/Choreographer(1999): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-15 06:20:05.618: D/dalvikvm(1999): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 381K, 10% free 4806K/5296K, paused 9ms, total 11ms
07-15 06:20:05.958: W/System.err(1999): org.json.JSONException: No value for orders
07-15 06:20:05.962: W/System.err(1999):     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:355)
07-15 06:20:05.982: W/System.err(1999):     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:549)
07-15 06:20:05.982: W/System.err(1999):     at learn2crack.asynctask.MainActivity$JSONParse.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:92)
07-15 06:20:05.994: W/System.err(1999):     at learn2crack.asynctask.MainActivity$JSONParse.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
07-15 06:20:05.998: W/System.err(1999):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
07-15 06:20:06.014: W/System.err(1999):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
07-15 06:20:06.014: W/System.err(1999):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
07-15 06:20:06.014: W/System.err(1999):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-15 06:20:06.014: W/System.err(1999):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-15 06:20:06.014: W/System.err(1999):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-15 06:20:06.014: W/System.err(1999):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 06:20:06.014: W/System.err(1999):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-15 06:20:06.014: W/System.err(1999):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-15 06:20:06.014: W/System.err(1999):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-15 06:20:06.014: W/System.err(1999):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Now the MainActivity

```
package learn2crack.asynctask;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import learn2crack.asynctask.library.JSONParser;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView uid;
TextView name1;
TextView email1;
Button Btngetdata;

//URL to get JSON Array
private static String url = "url"; //url contains private api key
//however, does contain json object, example object will be posted


//JSON Node Names 
////private static final String TAG_USER = "user";
private static final String TAG_ORDERS = "orders";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";

////JSONArray user = null;
JSONArray orders = null;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Btngetdata = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getdata);
    Btngetdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             new JSONParse().execute();


        }
    });


}



private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
     private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
         uid = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.uid);
         name1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
         email1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.email);
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // Getting JSON from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        return json;
    }
     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
         pDialog.dismiss();
         try {
                // Getting JSON Array
                //user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USER);
                orders = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ORDERS);
                ///JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(0);
                JSONObject c = orders.getJSONObject(0);

                // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);


                //Set JSON Data in TextView
                uid.setText(id);
                name1.setText(name);
                email1.setText(email);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


     }
}

}
```

The URL brings you to a JSON object that looks like this

```
{
  "orders": [
    {
      "buyer_accepts_marketing": true,
      "cancel_reason": null,
      "cancelled_at": null,
      "cart_token": 666,
      "checkout_token": 666,
      "closed_at": 666,
      "confirmed": true,
      "created_at": 666,
      "id": 666,
      "currency": "USD",
      "email": "user@gmail.com",
      "financial_status": "paid",
      "fulfillment_status": "fulfilled",
      "source": "browser",
      "name": "#1026",
      "note_attributes": [],
      "processing_method": "direct",
      "visiting_id": 666,
      "tags": "",
      "customer": {
        "accepts_marketing": true,
        "email": "user@gmail.com",
        "first_name": "firstname",
        "id": 666,
        "last_name": "lastname",
        "last_order_id": 666,
        "multipass_identifier": null,
        "note": null,
        "orders_count": 2,
        "verified_email": true,
        "tags": ""
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And the last bit is the JSONParser.java

```
package learn2crack.listview.library;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

I hope this isn't just something right in front of me, I've been working at this for a good bit now. I can also provide the layout and the manifest if need be, but I'm pretty sure those are good.

Comment: Post you json and parsing codes.

Comment: in json no field orders

Comment: posted the json and code.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple JSON parsing exception that is no value for **orders** 
you are trying to getString() on key **orders** that does not exist kindly check your json value pair combination..

Comment: It probably is simple, thank you for taking a look. I've just been trying and don't seem to be going anywhere. I've added additional code.